# Let [a, b] be divided into n equal parts, and let y1 be the value of f(x) at the midpoint of the ith subinvterval....

Tags: real-analysis

Let $[a, b]$ be divided into n equal parts, and let $y_1$ be the value of $f(x)$ at the midpoint of the ith subinvterval. The arithmetic mean of $y_1, \dots, y_n$ is

$A_n = (y_1 + \dots + y_n)/n$ 
show that $u = \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$. where
\begin{equation}
u = \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x) \, dx.
\end{equation}

I know the arithmetic mean is the same thing as the avergae of the integral (in this case $u$) and I know how to prove the arithmetic mean but I don't know what the question wants me to do? do I have to show that the arithmetic mean of $A_n$ is equal to $u$? but I don't know what the function is?

Comment: What you need to know about the function $f$ is that it is Riemann integrable. Then contemplate how the $A_n$ relate to Riemann sums and how these behave - *by definition* of Riemann integrable - as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Then write

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i^{*})\Delta x_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}\left ( \frac{b-a}{n} \right )=(b-a)A_{n}$,

where we have used the evident partition obtained from the data in the exercise.

Now it only remains take the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty $ and use the defnition of the Riemann integral.